# Travelling through France: subject to French restrictions re COVID-19?

Tags: uk, france, belgium, covid-19, eurostar

If I travel from the UK to France at the moment (20/03/2020) I need to provide proof that I am on an 'authorized outing', as per the regulations here:

https://www.gouvernement.fr/en/coronavirus-covid-19

I have booked a Eurostar train from London to Brussels; the route, of course, goes through France for a short period. Eurostar have texted and emailed me to say that these restrictions hold, but it's unclear whether these rules apply only to their trains to France. Do I still need a certificate to comply with the French government's rules even if I am going directly to Belgium?

Comment: https://uk.ambafrance.org/FAQ-recommandations-CORONAVIRUS-COVID-19#Puis-je-voyager-entre-la-France-et-le-Royaume-Uni _Nous recommandons d´éviter les déplacements intra-européens, même pour revenir sur le territoire national, à moins que des raisons impératives ne les y contraignent._ (_We recommend avoiding intra-European travel, even to return home, unless there are compelling reasons to do so_).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the UK Foreign office travel advice website
https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/france

> UK nationals can enter France if they have completed the necessary
>   “attestation” (see above) confirming that their travel is an
>   absolutely necessary journey.

Therefore, it seems that although you are just passing through France, because you are entering French territory then you must still comply with these restrictions.

It may be best to contact Eurostar and talk to them directly to find out more details for your situation and how they could help.

Edit:  As of 15:00 on Friday 20th March Belgium has also closed its borders for non-essential travel.

Source:  https://www.politico.eu/article/belgium-closes-borders-for-non-essential-travel/

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately Eurostar is very difficult to contact at the moment. Although I am traveling for work-related reasons (moving to a new home & starting a new job in the EU) I can technically telework. I am under the impression that the 'attestation' you refer to is the same as the one on the French gov't website: i.e. people who can work remotely are excluded.

Comment: People who travel for work reasons need an "attestation" from their employer in addition to the one they sign themselves. Also, note that Belgium is under lockdown as well, though with different rules.

Comment: Sorry, correction, in France, employees only need the certificate from the employer, not the personal one, for all work-related travel. But I doubt you would qualify.